# Как обьявить переменные класса, изменяемые одним методом и затем используемые другим?

Tags: графика, .net, c++, visual-studio

Добрый день, коллеги!

Полезла в СLR и вроде бы нарисовала фигурку, надо теперь чтобы она перерисовывалась в зависимости от рассчитанных координат по нажатию кнопки!

Вопрос: как и где объявить переменные координат, чтобы затем изменять их по нажатию кнопки (метод `button1_Click`) и измененные в этом методе использовать в другом методе `pictureBox1_Paint`. код ниже приведен.

```
public: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
          int a=System::Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1->Text);
          float alf=(a*90/20);
          x=int(100*(float (cos(alf))));
          y=int(100*(float (sin(alf))));

         }
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Paint(System::Object^  sender,System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {
Graphics^ g = this->CreateGraphics();
g->DrawArc(gcnew Pen(Color::Blue),10,10,200,200,180,180);
g->DrawLine(gcnew Pen(Color::Red), 10, 110, 210, 110); //Линия
g->DrawLine(gcnew Pen(Color::Black), 110, 110, x, y); //стрелка
```

Суть задачи: по нажатию кнопки берется число из текстбокса и рассчитываются координаты конца стрелки (линии), которая идет от центра полукруга в точку с данной координатой.
была мысль вызвать в методе `button1_Click` второй метод

```
 this->pictureBox1_Paint
 что то типа того или
 this->pictureBox1_Paint->DrawLine(х,у)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать перерисовку стрелки в зависимости от координат по нажатию кнопки.

Если мысль с вызовом в методе баттон правильная, помогите реализовать данный вызов.

P.S. На данный момент переменные х и у глобальные и видны в каждом методе как `test2::Form1::x`.

Заранее большое спасибо, сразу говорю что с++ и CLR только начала, поэтому желательно пример кода, в теории не всегда понятно как реализовывать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снимается! Сама дошла.

Если кому интересно, ответ: переменные глобальными остаются, в методе `button1_Click`  прописывается выхов метода рисования для перерисовки

```
this->pictureBox1->Invalidate();
```

После формул расчета переменных. И еще - угол alf переводится в радианы.

До этого не получалось вызывать потому что в методе рисования `Grafic`s нужно объявлять как

```
Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;
```

Чтобы зависел от параметров метода!

Век живи - век учись!